# How to prove $ A \cup \{a\} \approx B \cup \{ b \} \Rightarrow A \approx B $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to prove this without recurring to cardinality?

$ A \cup \{a\} \approx B \cup \{ b \} \Rightarrow A \approx B $

Where by "$ \approx $" I mean that there exists a bijective function between A and B (called equipollence, equipotence, equinumerosity). It seems fairly obvious because, if you get those additional elements out, then you have the same cardinality in both sides. The problem is, I have to find a way to prove it using the bijection definition.

So my guess is, I know that $ \exists f: (A \cup \{a\}) \rightarrow (B \cup \{ b \}) $ that is bijective. So there must exist $g: \{a\} \rightarrow \{ b \} $, which is clearly bijective, so that $\exists h: A \rightarrow B $ that is also bijective. The problem with this reasoning is that, I don't really know if this is true. What if the promised bijective function pairs some element from $A$ with $\{b\}$, and $\exists! x\in A , y \in B/ (x,y) \notin f$. Is this an issue at all? Or I can assume that this bijective function will pair each element from $A$ with each element in $B$, and $\{a\}$ with $\{b\}$?

**Edit:** To avoid confusions, I'm going to add some context. This is part of a bigger proof, namely: $ A \sqcup \{u\} \approx B \sqcup \{u\} \Rightarrow A \approx B $, where $\sqcup$ is disjoint union. This is the same as saying:

$ (A \times \{a\}) \cup \{(u,b)\} \approx (B \times \{c\}) \cup \{(u,d)\} \Rightarrow A \approx B $

Where $ a \neq b \wedge c \neq d $

In the original question I'm using $a$ instead of $\{(u,b)\}$, $b$ for $\{(u,d)\}$; $A$ for $(A \times \{a\})$, and $B$ for $(B \times \{c\})$

I think it's safe to assume that, knowing this, the original $a$ can't belong to the original $A$, and so on.

Comment: By the way your assuming $a \not \in A$ and $b \not \in B$.

Comment: @Rene: Or that $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, works too. :-)

Comment: Yeah but in that case the theorem is still true, if eg $a \in A$ but $b\not \in B$ then its false.

Comment: Well if they belong to each set, then I think the proof is trivial. So yes, I'm assuming that :)

Comment: My bad, just realized asking this question without context isn't a great idea. This is part of a bigger proof I'm trying to make, which involves disjoint union. Gonna edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume, $a\notin A$ and $b\notin B$ are assumed.

We are given a bijection $f:A\cup\{a\}\to B\cup\{b\}$. Compose it with the map $h$ that *swaps* $b$ and $f(a)$, and show that the composition restricted to $A$ is a bijection to $B$.

Answer (score 7):

Since you know that there is $f\colon A\cup\{a\}\to B\cup\{b\}$ which is bijection, if you knew that $f(a)=b$ you'd be finished, right? Because then the restriction of this $f$ to $A$ would have been a bijection with $B$.

But if not, the $f(a)=b'$ and there is some $a'$ such that $f(a')=b$. What can you do to rectify this situation?

Comment: I think the answer is to create a permutation $ g={{b^\prime \space b} \choose {b \space b^\prime}} \forall b^\prime / f(a) = b^\prime $ and compose it with $f$ so that $gof$ is the bijective function that can be restricted.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f:A\cup\{a\}\rightarrow B\cup\{b\}$ be a bijection. If $f(a)=b$ you are done.
Otherwise let $f(a)=y$ and $f(x)=b$ define $g:A\rightarrow B$ by $g(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ if $\alpha\neq x$ and $g(x)=y$ then it is easy to see $g$ is a bijection.

Comment: No, $g$ is only from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: How, my bad. Sorry